# What is the difference between $dxyabc and ${dxyabc} in Perl?

Tags: perl

What is the difference between definition of string `$dxyabc` and string `${dxyabc}` in Perl?

Answer (score 9):

Well, it depends on the context. For example,

```
$foo = "$dxyabcdef";
$bar = "${dxyabc}def";
```

`$foo` will have the value of `$dxyabcdef` instead of `$dxyabc` appended with `def`, this is the value of `$bar`.

Otherwise, as far as I know, they are the same.

Answer (score 8):

[`perldoc perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-value-constructors) explains why curlies are used in the context of scalar variables:

> As in some shells, you can enclose the variable name in braces to
>   disambiguate it from following alphanumerics (and underscores). You must also do this when 
>   interpolating a variable into a string to separate the variable name
>   from a following double-colon or an apostrophe, since these would be
>   otherwise treated as a package separator:
>
> ```
> $who = "Larry";
> print PASSWD "${who}::0:0:Superuser:/:/bin/perl\n";
> print "We use ${who}speak when ${who}'s here.\n";
> ```
>
> Without the braces, Perl would have looked for a `$whospeak`, a `$who::0` , and a
>   `$who's` variable. The last two would be the `$0` and the `$s` variables in
>   the (presumably) non-existent package `who` .

---

So as others have mentioned, there is no difference between `$dxyabc` and `${dxyabc}`. The quoted documentation explains why there is a difference between `"$dxyabc_"` and `"${dxyabc}_"`

Answer (score 0):

None, the braces are a delimiter around the variable name.

Comment: Your answer is only correct in some circumstances, Oesor.  See other answers for details on why it depends on the ${con}text.